# Adding functionality to a form in a React functional component

Tags: reactjs, forms, submit

I have a form component that when submitted uploads a photo to my server using multer and then to an S3 bucket on AWS in a single upload route. I want to add an extra line of functionality that stores the photo key from S3 in state on the front end which I will then store with the user object in the database so the photo is always associated with the user (profile picture).

The form sends properly as currently set up using the action parameter, but I'm not sure how to implement the submitHandler function into the form properly. If I remove the action parameter from the form it breaks, if I use onSubmit it also seems to break. I'm sure this is a really easy one but I can't figure it out. Any help much appreciated.

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

//setProfilePhoto is the set method for state from props

const UploadForm = ({setProfilePhoto}) => {

    const submitHandler = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const result = await axios.post('http://localhost:8000/api/upload');
        console.log(result.key)
        setProfilePhoto(result.key)
    }

    return(
        <form action="http://localhost:8000/api/upload" encType='multipart/form-data' method='POST'>
        <input type='file' name='photo' />
        <input type='submit' value="submit" />
        </form>
    )

}

export default UploadForm;
```

Answer (score 0):

try to take this line and delete it.  `<input type='submit' value="submit" />`
Replace it with a button.
Then add the onSubmit handler to the form tag, not the button.